# Editing Universal Page Header - Header.phtml.txt

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community, header

I'm not very familiar with Magento at all and I've been tasked with fixing something without a lot of training on the subject so please forgive me if my knowledge is lacking here.

I need to update the text on our website's home page from "4 pm" to "5 pm".  After quite a lot of googling I found that apparently that piece of text isn't a static block or a proper page.  What I did find, after downloading something like 30,000 files from the FTP to do a ctrl-f out of frustration is that there's a file called header.phtml.txt in

`app/design/frontend/default/<store_name>/template/page/html/`

That contains the string I'm looking to edit.  So I made the edit, dropped the file back into the FTP and refreshed the site's caches.

The change didn't take effect and I gave up.

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out why these changes aren't taking effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flush the cache!!!

especially if this is a production site then more than likely you will have cache turned on.

From the admin section - go to system>cache management. Flush all the caches! That should do it. Please report back and let us know!

For those coming from the future - the error was the file name. The .txt at the end of the file name was the error.

Comment: I've flushed Magento, Storage, Image, and Javascript/CSS caches and the content hasn't updated

Comment: One way that I find the block/item to edit is by turning on the template hints. To do this go into the admin then go to System>Configuration>Developer>Debug>Template Path Hints - change to yes, Make sure your Current Configuration Scope is set to the store you are using. Then save the admin setting and review the frontend of the site. You should see red boxes around the elements on the site. Once that is done - go to the file you wish to change via FTP. Flush the cache after and THAT should resolve it. Have a url to share by chance. Its not normal for a file that was uploaded not to show up.

Comment: Additionally - as I think about it - I dont think the file should be called header.phtml.txt - by default its header.phtml - so it may be that the text editor your using changed the format and when uploaded it defaults to the base header file.

Comment: Well it's fixed.  There were two files: header.phtml.txt and header.phtml.  I'm not sure why there were two but here we are.  The files were largely identical but the .txt one was out of date.

I checked through the non .txt one manually and found the same text there.  I guess I jumped the gun on the .txt file after spending 4 hours searching for the text.

Thank you for your help